# Python: Explanation of a Reversal Function

Tags: python, recursion

My professor posted the function below. I do not fully understand how it's working. Could someone explain it?

```
def rev(a):
    if a == []:
        return []
    else:
        return rev(a[1:]) + [a[0]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What this does is recursively reverses a list. The easiest way to see how it works is to [follow through the execution](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def+rev%28a%29%3A%0A++++if+a+%3D%3D+%5B%5D%3A%0A++++++++return+%5B%5D%0A++++else%3A%0A++++++++return+rev%28a%5B1%3A%5D%29+%2B+%5Ba%5B0%5D%5D%0A++++%0Ainitial+%3D+%5B1,+2,+3,+4%5D%0Aafter+%3D+rev%28initial%29&mode=display&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&drawParentPointers=false&textReferences=false&py=2&curInstr=2).

The function takes the string and solves it by returning the reversed version of all but the first item (`a[1:]`) with the first item appended to the end.

Note that this is a bad way to do this in a real situation (I am presuming your professor is just showing the idea of recursion), as Python isn't optimized for recursion. Instead, use [the `reversed()` builtin](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed).

Also, it isn't particularly Pythonic code. If one *had* to have a recursive solution, instead of using the efficient, effective, well-tested, easy-to-use built-in, consider:

```
def rev(seq):
    return rev(seq[1:]) + [seq[0]] if seq else []
```

- We use the ternary operator to condense the `if/else`.
- Replacing `a` with `seq` makes the function clearer - Python doesn't have strict typing, so using names that give a clue to what the function takes (in this case, a *sequence*), makes it clearer.
- We also replace the `a == []` by simply checking `seq`. As lists evaluate to `False` when empty, there is no need to compare to an empty list.

Comment: Plus you're slicing the list each time, which involves a copy. But I'm guessing this is just an illustrative Python implementation of the standard functional-programming (Scala/Erlang) idiom.

Comment: Sorry, I should've clarified. I know "what" it does, just not "how" it does it.

Comment: @Adam_G Follow my link at the beginning and step through the execution, it should make it supremely clear. Rather than clumsily trying to explain the steps here, that site visualizes the execution.

Comment: Thanks @Lattyware! I'd give you +100 just for that link -- it is very cool. This makes a lot more sense now; I guess I'm just not great about 'thinking recursively'.

Comment: @Adam_G It's a really great tool for when you struggle to get your head around how code/data is flowing. Recursive stuff can be hard to get, but once you get it, it becomes a surprisingly easy way to implement a lot of stuff, as you only have to think about two things: *how do I get a bit closer to the result I want?* and *how do I know when to stop?*. Obviously, as I mentioned in my post, there are optimization concerns with recursive methods, however.

Comment: You can always just do `my_list[::-1]`.

Comment: @F3AR3DLEGEND See my comment on antitrust's answer as to why that is a bad idea in general. `reversed()` should almost always be preferred.

Answer (score 2):

a is a list. If a is the empty list, you return the empty list. If not, you apply (recursively) your 'reverse' function to the list but the first element, and you append the first element. This way, at each recursive call for reverse, you build your reversed list beginning with its rightmost element.

This is an example:

```
l=[1,4,6,7]

rev(l) returns rev([4,6,7])+[1]
rev([4,6,7]) returns rev([6,7])+[4]
...
```

and in the end you have rev([]) returning the empty list and terminating the recursive calls.

BTW, to reverse a list `l`, just use

```
l[::-1]
```

Comment: While slicing with a step of `-1` is a good trick, it's generally a bad idea as it relies on the object implementing that. It's generally a better idea to use the `reversed()` built-in, which can let implementations special-case reversing for optimization and is much more readable.